# Shapes (893,) and (893, 16, 16, 15) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, conv-neural-network

Trying to push an array of images through a CNN with labelling. Most of this is code from elsewhere that  I am trying to make somewhat work in order to experiment and get something working that can detect the difference between an image with the object and an image without the object. Originally I was trying to do this with bounding box coordinates, but nothing I tried worked with that so I am settling for this while I figure a way to implement the coordinates.

```
    ntwk = x = layers.Input(shape=(256, 256, 3))
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.MaxPool2D()(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x) # size: 64x64x = layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)  # size: 64x64x = layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.MaxPool2D()(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)  # size: 32x32x = layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.MaxPool2D()(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)  # size: 16x16x = layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.MaxPool2D()(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x) # size: 8x8x
    
    x_prob = layers.Conv2D(1, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='sigmoid', name='x_prob')(x)#1
    x_boxes = layers.Conv2D(4, kernel_size=3, padding='same', name='x_boxes')(x)
    x_cls = layers.Conv2D(10, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='sigmoid', name='x_cls')(x)
    
    gate = tf.where(x_prob > 0.5, tf.ones_like(x_prob), tf.zeros_like(x_prob))
    x_boxes = x_boxes * gate
    x_cls = x_cls * gate
    
    x = layers.Concatenate()([x_prob, x_boxes, x_cls])
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(ntwk, x)
    model.summary()
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss="CategoricalCrossentropy")

    model.fit(dsx, batch_size=256, epochs=30, shuffle=True)
    print("done")
    
    return None
```

However I keep getting the following error:
ValueError: Shapes (893,) and (893, 16, 16, 15) are incompatible

the shapes of the np.arrays are [256,256,3] and [256] before turning them into a tensor (if it has the item or not). We do this to turn the arrays into tensors:
`dsx = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((trainimg,trainlab))`

Not really sure where the extra values are coming from, nor am I sure if theres a way to jury rig it.

Any help at all would be incredibly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can see it in the `model.summary()`. You start with `input.shape = (256x256x3)`, which go down to `x_prob.shape = (16,16,1)`, `x_boxes.shape = (16,16,4)`, `x_cls.shape = (16,16,10)`, which you then concatenate at `x = layers.Concatenate()([x_prob, x_boxes, x_cls])` to a shape `(16,16,15)`. The 15 comes from the sum of the filters, 1+4+10. This will get compared to the label, which is just one number.
Not sure how to solve this, as I'm not sure what you are trying to classify with how many classes. But you need to convert the 2D images to a flat number for classification. You can either do this with a [flatten layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Flatten), which would turn `(893,16,16,15)` to `(893,3840)` (16*16*15->3840), or a [GlobalAveragePooling](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GlobalAveragePooling2D) (or [GlobalMaxPooling](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GlobalMaxPooling2D)), which turns it to `(893,15)`. This you can follow this by a dense layer with the appropriate number of nodes to classify.

Also I don't know if it is meaningful to concatenate the 3 `x_prob, x_boxes, x_cls`, or if you want to handle them as 3 seperate outputs.

Comment: I understand it now, and have made the required edits. To clarify I have made a very simple (boardering on childlike) classifier of either 1 or 0 (the nature of the network is to analyse MRI scans to find tumors). Fortunately, when explained it works, unfortunately, the accuracy is 1.0 using this. Next step for me is figuring out how to make it try to detect where and draw bounding boxes where it thinks it is/where it actually is.